# How to find out Max Texture Size for WebGL on my system

Tags: javascript, webgl, textures

I am working on an application where I apply filters on HD images using WebGL. The problem that I am facing is that when I apply the filters using WebGL image gets cut away which is because of the limitation on part of WebGL in my system.

So my question is How do i find out the **max texture size of WebGL** on my system. Currently I know for sure that its set to 2048. as the images of 2048 x 2048 work perfectly fine and images greater than that are causing issues.

Comment: I did see that question. The problem I have is how do I find out Max Texture Size using javascript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum texture size of a `WebGLRenderingContext` is returned by [`gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/getParameter).
See the answer to the question ["Is it possible to use WebGL max texture size?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975743/is-it-possible-to-use-webgl-max-texture-size).

```js
function getMaxTextureSize() {
    var gl = document.getElementById( "my-canvas").getContext( "experimental-webgl" );
    if ( !gl )
      return;
    document.getElementById( "textureSize" ).innerHTML = gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE)
}
```

```html
<body onload="getMaxTextureSize();">
    MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE : <span id="textureSize">0</span>
    <canvas id="my-canvas" style="border: none;" width="64" height="64"></canvas>
</body>
```