# How to improve texture resolution in 3js

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping

I'm using 3js to display a sphere with a large texture map (6000x3000) but the image is being displayed with a disappointingly low resolution.

I am migrating to 3js from directly managing my scene with webGL and my own shader program, but in there I was getting the texture displayed with high detail. I noticed that 3Js automatically resizes texture maps to powers-of-2 sizes, and it warned that it was  resizing this image to 4096X2048.
When I externally resized my 6000x4000 image to 8192x4096, it no longer reported resizing, but the resolution remained poor: I would estimate at the equivalent of about 1024x512.

I'm running on a 27" Mac, with MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE 16384, so that's not the issue.
So Is there something I can do to improve the resolution from within 3js?

Comment: Note that even with `MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE=16384`, you may not be able to use a 16K texture, and certainly most of your users won't: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985986/1314762. I'd personally avoid anything larger than 4K, if you can. That said, I don't know why the texture would appear at a lower resolution when it does appear. You may find some ideas in this thread: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-can-i-increase-texture-sharpness/204

Comment: Could you show us a working demo of this effect? Maybe it's the WebGLRenderer's dimensions, or your texture filtering, or something else.

Comment: Don McCurdy: I don't think the issue not due to me exceeding max_texture_size because when I did exceed it in webGL, the browser failed to display the object.  It seem that 3Js is somehow reducing the image size without asking my permission!

Comment: Marquizzo: Not sure how the display of a fuzzy image would help. You suggest:  1)"WebGLRenderer's dimensions": which ones would affect the size of the texture map?, 2) "or your texture filtering" what is that?, 3)"or something else" yes, that's what I'm trying to discover.